# React navigation name issue

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-ios

Ive inherited some code here and I'm just confused as to how the app knows where the 'NextPage' is.

I call this:

```
            this.props.navigation.navigate('NextPage');
```

With this:

```
import { NavigationScreenProp } from 'react-navigation';

interface InitialLoadingScreenViewProps {
    navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any, any>
}
```

where is the 'NextPage' declared? so that when I create a new page I can create a navigation name for it. Ive tried using the search tool on VSCode but couldn't find it.

Comment: You have to declare your component screens inside **NavigationContainer** and give name **NextPage**. for more info forllow [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) to see how to declare screens and [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating) to know how to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would know what type of react-navigation are you using (stack, drawer, etc).

If you are using stack navigator, you have to create your stack navigator with the screens you have created in the "App.js". First you import the screens in the top of the file, with the name that you export them in their js file. Then, in the createStackNavigator function, you assign any name you want to each screen for the navigation (for example I assign the name "Home" for my HomeScreen). Finally, to use the navigate function, you will have to pass the name of the screen that you have assigned. See the next to files to understand it better. The fist one is an "App.js" example and the seconde one a "HomeScreen.js" example:

```
import React from 'react';
        import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
        import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
        import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen.js';
        import DetailsScreen from "./src/screens/DetailsScreen.js";
        const navigator = createStackNavigator({
          Home: HomeScreen,
          Details: DetailsScreen,
        },{
          initialRouteName: 'Home',
          defaultNavigationOptions : {
            title: 'App'
          }
        });
export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

---

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button title='Tap to navigate' onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Details')}/>
    </View>
    );
};
export default HomeScreen;
```

In this example I have created those two screens as Components. If you create them with "class HomeScreen extends Component" maybe you will have to use `this.props.navigation.navigate('NextPage');` as you said.

In case you need more help or information visit the react-navigation website at:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started